# PostgreSQL database stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

Create stored procedure `getoperatordetails` in postgresql database.

Getting the three parameters in another stored procedure, but it is causing error, avoid the error and will get result True (or) False

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getoperatordetails(value character varying, operator     character varying, fieldinputvalue character varying, retvalue boolean)
      RETURNS SETOF boolean AS
    $BODY$
    declare
    iVal numeric;
    gVal numeric;
    begin
    IF fieldInputValue != ' ' AND operator!='equal' THEN

    gVal := value :: numeric;
    iVal := fieldInputValue:: numeric;

    IF (operator = ('lesserThan') AND iVal < gVal) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSIF (operator = ('greaterThan') AND iVal > gVal) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSIF (operator = ('lessOrEqual') AND iVal <= gVal) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSIF (operator = ('greaterOrEqual') AND iVal >= gVal) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSIF (operator = ('equal') AND value = (fieldInputValue)) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSE
    retValue= false;

    END IF;

    ELSIF (operator=('equal') AND value=(fieldInputValue)) THEN
    retValue= true;

    ELSE
    retValue= false;

    END IF;
    return next retValue;
    end;

    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100
      ROWS 1000;
    ALTER FUNCTION getoperatordetails(character varying, character varying, character varying, boolean)
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

I need to get the result True (or) False

> ERROR:  argument of AND must not return a set
>   LINE 1: SELECT retValue AND getoperatordetails(value, operator, fiel...)

Comment: Is this the Way what u want ? or else edit ur query and forward it back. . .[Check This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/44a68/2)

Comment: Hi, I need to avoid the error and will return type True (or) False

Comment: when did this procedure raised a error! what sort of query evaluation did u gave..

Comment: Hi, I am passing three parameters: retValue = retValue AND getoperatordetails(value, operator, fieldinputvalue, retvalue);

Comment: I cant get u clear enough can u keep ur code into a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12) and please give the format in the which u r trying to call the function and use it

Comment: This is What My understanding is all about[Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6029d/3)

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in declaration of this function. It is declared as "RETURNS SETOF boolean", what is nonsense. Probably you would to write a scalar function, so declaration should be "RETURNS boolean" - you have to use "RETURN" instead "RETURN NEXT" then.

Second issue: you use a C style of programming - plpgsql is interpreted language and you should to minimize a number of instructions - so using a auxiliary value for result is not good - your code will be 2x slower. You can use a CASE construct instead nested IF - or better, you can use a just SQL function instead PL/pgSQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(op text, a int, b int)
RETURNS bool AS $$
SELECT CASE op 
         WHEN '=' THEN a = b
         WHEN '<' THEN a < b
         WHEN '>' THEN a > b
       END;       
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Personally, It looks like you try to create new interpret language - create interpret in interpreted language is not best idea - really.